# Getting an ID string when selecting a cell

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am making an iPhone app with different views, one of these being an UITableView, and i want to pass an ID string to another view, depending on the selected row.I have multiple row selection.I don't want to pass the data of the cell, but an ID to associate with it.
F.E: Cell name: "United States", to return a NSString: "09r454-0567-34".I don't have an idea of how to associate these strings to a cell.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need to declare an array of dictionaries, then you catch didSelectRowAtIndexPath:, and retreive the information in that array

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSDictionary *dict = [myIDArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"ID %@", [dict objectForKey:@"ID"]);
    NSLog(@"Name %@", [dict objectForKey:@"Name"]);
}
```

NSArray* myIDArray; //must be declared in .h

Hope this help...

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think it will be helpful,but excuse me to ask another question: I've seen in another post how to pass strings to another view, but if i select f.e. 6 cells, i want their respective ID's to be putted in one string, dividing them by just an "&" character.Sorry for all these questions, but I'm new to Objective-C and iPhone programming.Thanks for any answer.

Comment: uhmmm following the above code you may write something like this to concatenate all strings...

 NSMutableString *paramString = [[[NSMutableString alloc] init] autorelease];
 
 for(NSDictionary *paramInfo in myIDArray)
     [paramString appendFormat:@"%@&", [paramInfo objectForKey:@"ID"];